# jQuery Shorthand for multiple addClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this bit of code:

```
$("body.ow-client1 #stage-nav li.nav1 a").addClass("sub-nav-active");
$("body.ow-client2 #stage-nav li.nav2 a").addClass("sub-nav-active");
$("body.ow-client3 #stage-nav li.nav3 a").addClass("sub-nav-active");
$("body.ow-client4 #stage-nav li.nav4 a").addClass("sub-nav-active");
$("body.ow-client5 #stage-nav li.nav5 a").addClass("sub-nav-active");
$("body.ow-client6 #stage-nav li.nav6 a").addClass("sub-nav-active");
$("body.ow-client7 #stage-nav li.nav7 a").addClass("sub-nav-active");
$("body.ow-client8 #stage-nav li.nav8 a").addClass("sub-nav-active");
$("body.ow-client9 #stage-nav li.nav9 a").addClass("sub-nav-active");
```

That's all well and good, but I'm wondering if there's a shorthand to write that?

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're trying to navigate? Those are some very specific selectors. There may be a more general selector you could use.

Comment: Well, if you are on Client1's page, the side navigation for that client is highlighted in an unordered list, etc.

Comment: Have you got more than one element with `id="stage-nav"`? Or is the idea behind those selectors to only apply the class when when the body has one of those `.ow-clientX` classes?

Comment: The latter, correct: 1 selector is applied when the body has class `.ow-clientX`

Comment: This should probably be done on the server.  Add the active class to the navigation element based on the page that was requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  var sel = 'body.ow-client' + i + ' #stage-nav li.nav' + i + ' a';
  $(sel).addClass("sub-nav-active");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what if in the future additional clients are added? (the number goes beyond "9")?

Comment: @Yahreen then just switch the loop conditional from `9` to the appropriate number.

Comment: You should never have a `var` inside a loop. Move it outside and above the loop.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you could just concat selectors together:

```
$("body.ow-client1 #stage-nav li.nav1 a, body.ow-client2 #stage-nav li.nav2 a, body.ow-client3 #stage-nav li.nav3 a").addClass("sub-nav-active");
```

But this is harder to read. Why do you need to have numbered `ow-clientX` classes?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the only way you can do that.

```
$("body.ow-client9 #stage-nav li a").addClass("sub-nav-active");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this without JS code, by putting it in the style sheet:

```
<style>

body.ow-client1 #stage-nav li.nav1 a,
body.ow-client2 #stage-nav li.nav2 a,
body.ow-client3 #stage-nav li.nav3 a,
/* ... */
body.ow-client9 #stage-nav li.nav9 a {
                                       /* styles 
                                          from sub-nav-active
                                          here */
                                     }
</style>
```

You wouldn't actually have a class called `sub-nav-active` anymore, you'd just apply the appropriate styles using the selectors as shown above.

(Obviously this solution only works if the only point of having `sub-nav-active` is to apply styles to the anchor elements within the active section: if you are also using it in other JS code as a jQuery selector then it wouldn't work.)